# Merging RGB layers of V4L2 device in Simulink

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink

I'm currently working on car counter/tagging project with Raspberry Pi on Simulink. I have problems with converting outputs of seperate RGB channels into one multidimensional. I've tried add/sum block but it gave me something like grayscale video frames.

[Simulink image of my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8EMS.png)

Comment: have you tried 'vector concatenate' block in multidimensional mode ?

Comment: @Umar It adds R-G-B channels one by one as vertically or horizantally. 640x480 becomes 640x1440.